# SecurityAccessDeniedException Access is denied

Tags: wcf, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am experiencing a strange behavior with our ssl certificate. I am not sure how to explain best but here goes, I am getting access denied exception when im inside the office network but the form submits fine when im on my home network or using a 3g connection. sometimes the form fails randomly even when i am connected from my home internet provider.

Can someone explain why this is sporadic. certificates shouldnt affect what network you are on?

and the exception log

Process information:
    Process ID: 6268
    Process name: w3wp.exe
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Exception information:
    Exception type: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException
    Exception message: Access is denied.

Request information:
    User: 
    Is authenticated: False
    Authentication Type: 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

I forgot to add the exception is sporadic only outside of the office network, inside the office network the web service call fails 100%

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I think the problem has to do with permissions. Are you using different accounts/computers between work and home?

It sounds like your work account isn't allowed to modify network services (depending on your IT configuration) on home versions an administrator typically has access to all services. Open an administrative command prompt and type

```
net localgroup YOUR_USERNAME_OR_GROUPNAME networkservice /add
```

You might also have to add yourself to the *service* group in general (otherwise adding network services may have no effect)

```
net localgroup YOUR_USERNAME_OR_GROUPNAME localservice /add
```

Comment: Ok I also think the problem is with permission. But the web  application is hosted on a windows server. Its a typyicsl mv4 web application and no logging in is required. The only thing different between my home PC and work is the internet connection. Also why do you say modify network services ?

Comment: I said modify services because the error said "authority/network service" I've seen similar messages that were fixed with my solution. But I suppose if it was because network services it never would've worked. But yours is sporadic so it sounds like you have a different problem. Sorry I couldn't help. Good luck

Comment: Anyone who comes here reading this. Consider the impact of adding NetworkService to Administrators group. "Hello hacker, glad you made it in, here's full system access." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx ... This is not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: thanks @TeddHansen I'm not denying you are right, I'm certainly not an expert by any means, so please correct me if I'm wrong: The text near the bold __administrators__ says to replace with your own username/usergroup. Isn't this just adding the extra role to your own account? If run as is, I can now see that may be a problem. I'll update my response once I correctly understand the issue,Thanks for your info

Comment: `net localgroup administrators networkservice /add` would add networkservice user to administrators group. NetworkService described as "It has minimum privileges on the local computer and acts as the computer on the network." Administrators described as "Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain" ... "Administrator" is the user, but "Administrators" is the group. Second parameter (NetworkService and LocalService) is the user being added to the group. Ref https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490706.aspx  Verified locally (run command and check group).

Comment: @TeddHansen thanks for the clarification, I would hate to inadvertently put someones computer at risk. Is my updated solution acceptable? Also feel free to edit it if its not. Thanks

Comment: It helps somewhat that its not Administrator-access, but NetworkService is the user that runs network daemons. The reason it has lower privileges on the system is so that attackers would gain minimal access to the system if they use a remote exploit to gain access. This is a fundamental security concept found in all modern operating systems. Breaking it means lowering security. In the case of this specific error I would guess there is another solution. IIS is not designed so NetworkService needs elevated rights, worst case just give the site elevated rights.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's a `serviceAuthorization` behavior defined in your web.config, it might call some custom class which implements `ServiceAuthorizationManager`, does some authentication and fails (for example returns false from CheckAccessCore).